# Pandas drop duplicates on one column and keep only rows with the most frequent value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks as the following:

```
ip_address    malware_type
ip_1          malware_1
ip_2          malware_2
ip_1          malware_1
ip_1          malware_1
ip_1          malware_2
ip_2          malware_2
ip_2          malware_3
.
.
.
```

I want to drop duplicate rows based on the 'ip_address' column, however when the dropping occurs, I want to keep only the 'malware_type' value that is the most frequent for each IP. So the resulting dataframe should look like:

```
ip_address    malware_type
ip_1          malware_1
ip_2          malware_2
.
.
.
```

I would really appreciate any help to achieve the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `mode`

```
s=df.groupby('ip_address').malware_type.agg(lambda x : x.mode()[0]) # .reset_index()
Out[56]: 
ip_address
ip_1    malware_1
ip_2    malware_2
Name: malware_type, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @BEN_YO, your solution was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html)

```
df.groupby('ip_address').malware_type.agg(pd.Series.mode)

ip_address
ip_1    malware_1
ip_2    malware_2
Name: malware_type, dtype: object
```

You can use [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) here.

```
from scipy.stats import mode
df.groupby('ip_address').malware_type.agg(lambda x: mode(x).mode)

ip_address
ip_1    malware_1
ip_2    malware_2
Name: malware_type, dtype: object
```

Another is to use [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)'s [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method.

```
def md(s):
    c = Counter(s)
    return c.most_common(1)[0][0]

df.groupby('ip_address').malware_type.agg(md)

ip_address
ip_1    malware_1
ip_2    malware_2
Name: malware_type, dtype: object
```